# Override default breakpoints in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, css, less-css

I want to override default breakpoints in magento2 css. suggest any ideas how to do this?

E.g. in magento2 default breakpoints are

```
@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 480px;

@screen__s: 640px;

@screen__m: 768px;

@screen__l: 1024px;

@screen__xl: 1440px;
```

I want to override them by

```
@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 479px;

@screen__s: 767px;

@screen__m: 991px;

@screen__l: 1440px;

@screen__xl: 2150px;
```

On Devdocs magento I found the way to add new but failed to override existing alls.

Comment: try the below given answer, and provide your feedback

Answer (score 3):

In magento 2.x, overriding variables, we can do in many place.

But recommended way fpr override variables in `_theme.less`, so it will apply to entire theme

> app\design\frontend[VENDOR][THEME]\web\css\source_theme.less

And Note

> Best Practices Says **add comments for future re-use or easy to understand code**

so in _theme.less at the begin add below code or add your code as you wish.

```
//
//  Responsive variables
//  _____________________________________________

@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 479px;

@screen__s: 767px;

@screen__m: 991px;

@screen__l: 1440px;

@screen__xl: 2150px;
```

After adding  your changes  to `_theme.less` do below steps.

1. Clear `pub/static/*` in static folder clear all except .httaccess
2. Clear `var/*` in var folder clear all  except .httaccess
3. Deploy the static content :  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` , In developer mode you can't deploy without adding `-f` in command

& after deploy, See store front you will achieve your desired output.